# How to JSON dump an array containing element names and element values in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, amazon-web-services, iot

I am parsing/decoding array element names from JSON message and I need to give some random number values to its element names and then have to JSON dump that array (including element names that I parsed and its random values that I gave). The JSON message I parsed is similar to

```
{ "lib": {  "p1": "xyz", "p2": "lmn", "p3": "opq"  } }
```

and the JSON message I want to dump should be like,

```
{"foo":  {"bar": { "xyz": "15", "lmn": "33", "opq": "53"  } } }
```

I am doing it by "for loop" to handle array elements, but didn't get expected flow. Any one can help ?!

Note : numbers of JSON element names are not fixed, it can be 3 or 5 or 10 or more then 50 even.

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about your expected inputs and outputs? Are you always interested in only the keys of "lib"? Can there be more nesting inside of that object?

What have you tried so far, and what exactly went wrong?

Comment: This isn't really a JSON question. You parse the message using `json.load`, manipulate the resulting `dict`, and dump the result with `json.dump`. It's step 2 that you are asking about.

Comment: You mention arrays multiple times but have shown no JSON data or code that has, or deals with, arrays. Where do arrays come into this?

Comment: well, I have solved that by myself, sorry for informing late. But thank you all for your attention and time.

Answer (score 0):

After few trials and errors, finally I got it done, I am putting only few parts of my code at here.

```
def customCallback(client, userdata, message):
   print("Received a new message: ")
   print(message.payload)
   parser = json.loads(message.payload)
   print ("parser : ",parser)
   global lib
   global para
   global payload
   if (parser["lib"]):
     global params
     global tags
     lib = []
     para = []
     payload = 'null'
     params = 1
     tags = parser["lib"]
     print ("tags : ", tags)
     for i in tags:
       print (tags[i])
       lib.append(tags[i])
     print (lib)
   for i in range(len(lib)):
     para.append({lib[i]:random.randint(0,100)})
   print ("para array", para)
   payload = json.dumps({'foo':{'bar':para}})
   print ("payload in callback", payload)

myMQTTClient.subscribe(subscribe_topic, 1, customCallback)
while 1:
  if params == 1:
    myMQTTClient.publish(publish_topic, payload, 0)
    print ("payload published", payload)
  time.sleep(10)
```